# flask_sqlalchemy: AbstractConcreteBase not mapped until subclass is queried

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am currently working on a project involving the frameworks flask and sqlalchemy. The basic idea is having a ticket system, with different kind of tickets available.

A simplified version of my code can be found here: https://github.com/Birne94/flask-sqlalchemy-ticket-setup (runnable through `python app.py`).

The setup involves a set of models, which are:

- Base: The base class for all models, basically just defines an `id` and the table name

  - TimestampMixin: A mixin for adding timestamps to models, like creation or update timestamps
  - Ticket: The main cause of trouble I am currently having. An abstract base class for all kinds of tickets.
  - TestTicket: Some ticket class for demo purposes

The current issue, I am having is the following:

When trying to query the `Ticket` class, I will receive an error like:

`sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: SQL expression, column, or mapped entity expected - got '<class 'models.Ticket'>'`

Full stacktrace: https://gist.github.com/Birne94/bac3254163c8248df192521729857641

I was experimenting a lot with my setup, having no success. Randomly, I tried adding a query to the subclass before my initial query, and it worked.

After diving deeper into the code, it appears the mappers are first configured, when the subclass is queried. This does not happen when querying the base class.

This is demonstrated in the example I linked above (`app.py`, line 15 ff). If I access the endpoint, the first query will fail. After executing the second query (which works), the query that failed initially, will now work:

`query failed
query successful on second try
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Oct/2016 14:42:22] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -`

Now... is there something obvious I am missing/doing wrong or is there an actual issue with configuring mappers in SQLAlchemy?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you inherit from `AbstractConcreteBase` it will defer the creation of `Mapper` objects for that base class.

The inter-mapping relationships won't be configured until `configure_mappers` is called. Points at which `configure_mappers` is called include when a mapped class is instantiated into an instance, as well as when the `Session.query()` method is used.

Further, since you inherit from `AbstractConcreteBase` no mapping is made to a persistent table and the `Ticket` class will never be instantiated directly. Therefore, there is no `Ticket` table nor is there any inter-mapping relationship at the point when you first call the Query on `Ticket`, resulting in the error you mentioned.

At the point when you query `TestTicket` -- `configure_mappers` is called and the inter-mapper relationship is created, allowing you to query `Ticket`.

You should see the same behavior if you make an instance `TestTicket` rather than querying it, as this event will also cause `configure_mappers` to be called.

If you intended for there to be a persistent table created for the `Ticket` class, you should inherit from `ConcreteBase` instead.

As evidenced by your findings, calling `configure_mappers` manually seems to clear up this problem.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. You are right, creating a `TestTicket` works as well. `Ticket` is meant to not be persisted, but a queryable base class. From the example given in the [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html#sqlalchemy.ext.declarative.AbstractConcreteBase) I should be able to query the base class directly. I understand the mapper configuration being delayed here, but why doesn't it happen at all? Can I trigger this manually?

Comment: @Birne94 I would have thought it would have configured after the models were all defined. I believe it could be that there is no discriminator defined (`polymorphic_on` field in `mapper_args`), which is needed if you want to do polymorphic loading (the usual case; I believe this is what you want) -- If not defined, it can instead be defined on a derived select statement that’s used when the class is queried, but is not a typical configuration. And/or try `with_polymorphic` for the query to `Ticket` -- I'm not 100% sure on this or whether you can call `configure_mappers` manually. Worth trying.

Comment: Neither adding `polymorphic_on` nor using `with_polymorphic` resulted in a working query. I resolved it by calling `configure_mappers` on application startup, which appears to configure everything correctly.

Comment: @Birne94 Glad to hear you were able to find that resolution! Somewhat unique in my opinion that it would not be called automatically, as [the docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapping_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.configure_mappers) suggest should happen "in most cases." Haven't run across that before. Anyhow, cheers!